# pass video duration when 'play' is pressed using ajax

Tags: ajax, html5-audio

On a page I have an audio file and saved in a PHP variable is the duration of the audio.

I already know how to pass information to another page via ajax by using a code similar to below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "www.mydomain.com/passtothispage",
    data: {"time":"duration"},
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#divid').html(data);
    }
});
```

What I'm stuck on is how to pass the audio duration PHP variable only when 'PLAY' is pressed.

Thanks!

B

Answer (score 0):

You can use the play event of the video/audio. It is fired "when the audio/video has been started or is no longer paused". Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_play.asp

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.onplay = function() {
    alert("The video has started to play");
    //then you can use your ajax to send the duration here.
};
```

To get the duration property, `vid.duration` using the same `vid` object specified in the code sample above. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp